# self:: vs className:: inside static className methods in PHP

Tags: php, class, static

I guess there may not be any difference but personal preference, but when reading various PHP code I come across both ways to access the methods class.

What *is* the difference:

```
class Myclass
{
    public static $foo;

    public static function myMethod ()
    {
        // between:
        self::$foo;
        // and
        MyClass::$foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I gave a wrong answer the first time. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

(Note: the initial version said there was no difference. Actually there is)

There is indeed a small diference. `self::` forwards static calls, while `className::` doesn't. This only matters for [late static bindings](http://php.net/lsb) in PHP 5.3+.

In static calls, PHP 5.3+ remembers the initially called class. Using `className::` makes PHP "forget" this value (i.e., resets it to `className`), while `self::` preserves it. Consider:

```
<?php
class A {
    static function foo() {
        echo get_called_class();
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static function bar() {
        self::foo();
    }
    static function baz() {
        B::foo();
    }
}
class C extends B {}

C::bar(); //C
C::baz(); //B
```

Comment: Important correction/addition: the `static` keyword was introduced for  this purpose. Add a `const FOO = __CLASS__;` to each A, B and C, and make `A::foo()` print both `self::FOO` and `static::FOO`. Only the latter will actually be correct for `C::baz()`.

Comment: @Artefacto which would you recommend for a typical application that doesn't use late static bindings? Would you opt for `self::` or `MyClass::`? Which did you suggest performed more efficiently? Thanks

Comment: @Lea It's mostly a matter of style, but `self::` can be more handy when refactoring.

Comment: @Artefacto thanks for clarifying that, I'll stick to `self::` then as that is what I have been using. I came across this question and was curious if there would be a useful performance boost.

Comment: To clarify @janmoesen's comment: **The following is wrong:**: *"`self::` forwards static calls"*. NO, the linked document shows that `self::` **does not forward** static calls. If you want forwarding (Late Static Binding), use `static::`. This would be seen if `C` also defined `static function foo() { echo "Truth"; }`. If LSB occurred, `C::bar` would echo "Truth". But it won't. (Tested) So how does `C::bar` echo "C"? When `C::bar` is about to execute, `C` is stored in some internal php location: *"late static bindings work by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call"."*

Comment: ... so this example demonstrates the first half of LSB - the storage of classname `C`. However `self::foo` does not use that classname, when finding which version of `foo` to execute. `static::foo` would do the correct search for function version.  **If this explanation goes over your head, then you probably don't have code where it matters**. Use `self::` for convenience. Until you encounter a situation where it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With self you can use it within the class and with the "MyClass", as you have, you can reference it externally:

```
$instance = new Myclass();
$variable = $instance::$foo
```