# Call to undefined function with PHP

Tags: php, function, undefined, scopes

I have this class:

```
class testclass{
    function func1(){
        return "hello";
    }
    function func2(){
        echo func1();
    }
}
```

When I am running

```
$test = new testclass();
$test->func2();
```

I get an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function func1()` with the line index of `echo func1();`

My question now is, how do I make the `func2` recognize `func1`

Is this a problem with the scopes?

Comment: `func1()` refers to the *global* function `func1()`. Not the `func1()` of the current class. To call the `func1()` in the current class you'd use `$this->func1()` (or `self::func1()` if it's a static method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function func2(){
        echo func1();
    }
```

should be

```
function func2(){
        echo $this->func1();
    }
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

[self:: vs className:: inside static className metods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481085/self-vs-classname-inside-static-classname-metods-in-php)

Comment: and where is the difference to `echo testclass::func1()` ?

Comment: The `::` operator indicates that `func1()` is a static method of `testclass`, which isn't the case.

Comment: You can check more about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481085/self-vs-classname-inside-static-classname-metods-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You're using OO techniques, so you'll have to use the `$this` keyword to access the `func1()` function:

```
class testclass
{
    function func1()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    function func2()
    {
        echo $this->func1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code, you cannot invoke the function like this, the proper way is by using `$this` (which refers to the class itself):

```
class testclass
{
    function func1()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    function func2()
    {
        echo $this->func1();
    }
}
```